# Select from list of tables / multiple tables with nested query - MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, nested

Not sure if this has an easy answer, but I'm basically trying to do this:

```
select id
from (select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'id') 
where id = 1234
```

So passing in a list of tables into the FROM.

I'm trying to check all tables where this column exists if they have a matching value for 1234.

And without typing 31 times, select from table1, select from table2, etc etc

And without doing a bunch of joins.

possible?

Comment: Possible using a stored procedure, but not with plain SQL I believe! i.e. you need "Dynamic SQL" not "Static SQL".

Comment: Please tag the database being used

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product - and as you will need dynamic SQL, this is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Great thanks all, I know where to go from here!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this stored procedure.

It SUCKS I know, I've never written anything in tsql (teesquill?) before, and my goal was just to get something that *works*.

// find all occurrences of value in DB

```
USE [your db here]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_query] (

@value NVARCHAR(128),
@colName NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- DECLARE @tables NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tabName NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- DECLARE @colName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @count INT;


-- construct SQL
--SET @tables = N'SELECT Table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE "yourcollumn"'

DECLARE tabs CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'yourcollumn'

OPEN tabs
    FETCH NEXT FROM tabs INTO @tabName

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0

BEGIN
    
    --SET @count = N'SELECT count ( ' + @colName + ' ) FROM ' + @tabName + ' where ' + @colName + ' = ' + @value

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);  
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);  
    DECLARE @varOut NVARCHAR(25); 

    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @count = count ( ' + @colName + ' ) FROM ' + @tabName + ' where ' + @colName + ' = ' + @value;  

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@count NVARCHAR(25) OUTPUT';  
    
    

    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString  
    ,@ParmDefinition  
    ,@count = @varOut OUTPUT;


    SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM ' + @tabName + ' where yourcollumn = ' + @value;

    IF @varOut > 0
        SELECT @tabName AS 'value found in table'
        --EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        
    FETCH NEXT FROM tabs INTO @tabName
END
CLOSE tabs
```

END;